# Online Database with laravel needs classes?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a complete database hosted and I want to integrate it into my laravel new project. All I know is how to change the env file and I did so. There is a couple of questions though:

- Does using online database with laravel need creating classes?
- What should I add to the env file? This from my env file:

  DB_CONNECTION=MySQL
  DB_HOST=(my server IP)
  DB_PORT=3306
  DB_DATABASE=*name*
  DB_USERNAME=*done*
  DB_PASSWORD=*done*

What else should I add and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Laravel with Database you have to specify which database you want to connect (Live/Local). You can configure your database credentials in **.env** and **database.php** inside config folder.

Most preferred way is by using .env from the root directory/folder. Doing this it will be easier for deploying in multiple instances like UAT, PROD, etc.

Comming back to your questions:

- Does using online database with laravel need creating classes? I assume you refer to models.

The answer is **Yes** and **No**.

> **NO**: If you want to use [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries).
>
> **YES**: If you want to use [Elloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent).

I personally prefer using Elloquent ORM instead of writing lots of dirty join query and beyond. Once you get the hang of it, you will never step away from Elloquent ORM. It take a bit of time to learn but worth the time you will invest.

- What should I add to the env file? This from my env file:

I think you are good with your current .env

Good luck and happy learning.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed  answer . So I have to create them manually? I mean the classes

Comment: You can create manually or using the artisan command. It is easier if you use artisan as the boilerplate are generated for you. the command is 'php artisan make:model yourmodelnamehere'

Comment: Thank you very much